# How to set a maximum execution time of a script with node.js?

Tags: node.js, execution-time

I give my users a flexible way to transform data using JavaScript, executed with Node.js on server-side. With that design, there is 3 issues to consider :

- Security : I solved the security issue using a [sandbox](http://gf3.github.com/sandbox/) to avoid usage of native Node.js libraries.
- Resources : we can easily set maximum memory usage using v8 option `--max_executable_size`. About the CPU usage, I'll see how to manage it using `cpulimit` or `renice`, it does not really matter now.
- Time : I need to limit execution time of my scripts, to avoid them running as hangry zombies. And here I get stuck.

I tried something like :

```
 node -e '
    setTimeout(function() {
       console.log("timeout");
       process.exit;
    }, 5000);
    console.log("begin");
    while (1);
 '
```

But this code displays only "begin", it seems that my timeout is never called.
Any idea ?

Comment: Are these your scripts?  Or are you trying to limit execution of arbitrary code?  Are you trying to set a time limit on the whole application?  Or a chunk of code within?

Comment: I want to limit execution of a chunk of code within.

Comment: your "while(1);" is blocking execution, remove it and you'll see both begin and timeout.

Comment: This `while(1)` may be used by my users. I chose my example in a bad usecase, the usecase that will need to be limited :-).

Comment: Why can't you use the sandbox module for that too? If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/gf3/sandbox/blob/master/lib/sandbox.js#L32-L36) you can see that you can provide a timeout option for the child processes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, if your users can initiate blocking operations (like `while(1)`), there's no way to tell Node to exit after a certain time, as the blocking operation will prevent the `setTimeout` handler from firing. Either ensure that user-initiated stuff won't block the main loop, or (and this is a *very* bad idea) use some sort of external auto-kill/timeout to destroy the Node process.

Basically, you can use Node to limit the execution time of *nonblocking* code, but the whole point of Node is that blocking code blocks everything. If your users are truly capable of running arbitrary code, I'd consider running your process manager/timeout-killer at a higher level: for example, spawning processes with kill timeouts using Node's [exec](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) facility.

Comment: Ah, ok, in such a case, I'll use `timeout 5s` just before `node` command, this will kill my process too. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you go that route, make sure that whatever your Node process is doing is something that a) doesn't break things if it aborts in the middle of an operation, and b) won't leave un-freed resources on your system (this happens when some programs are sent a `kill -9`).

Comment: Actually, the [sandbox I use](http://gf3.github.com/sandbox/) does what you are speaking about (I see some execs and sigkills after a timeout, managed by a parent process). Didn't seen it first because all examples uses default values... Nice anyway.

Answer (score 9):

You might want to look at tripwire (https://github.com/tjanczuk/tripwire). It is a module that can kill runaway node scripts and you can set a timeout. It is a native node module, so that is one thing to consider, but it works on Mac, Windows and Linux.

Comment: My question is a bit old now, but your answer looks very interesting.

Comment: @AlainTiemblo lol I see that now. This was passed to me from someone on my team who just found this. It'll be there now for anyone who searches. :p

Comment: Yes, that's why "Necromancer" badge exists :-) Some fresh answers can fit old questions better. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

Node's [built-in `vm` module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) offers `module.evaluate`, `script.runInContext` and several other methods which will run code in a sandboxed environment and which take a `timeout` option to specify the maximum time (in ms) to allow the VM to run for.

Do note that running untrusted code in Node.js is *fraught with potential security issues*. Even the VM module specifically says "**The vm module is not a security mechanism. Do not use it to run untrusted code.**"  (Why not?  [Here is one reason why not](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-use-cases-for-the-Node-js-vm-core-module): it looks like it should be harmless to run `vm.runInNewContext("this.constructor.constructor('return process')().exit()")` but in fact it will cause Node to terminate.

You may alternatively wish to consider using [Patrik Simek](https://github.com/patriksimek)'s [vm2](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2) which offers similar functionality but claims to "run untrusted code with whitelisted Node's built-in modules. Securely!"  An example from the documentation:

```
const {VM} = require('vm2');

const vm = new VM({
    timeout: 1000,
    sandbox: {}
});

vm.run("process.exit()"); // throws ReferenceError: process is not defined
```